# DPD weight function

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, weight, dissipation, fluctuation-dissipation

I was wondering about the connection between the weight function of the random force and the conservative force between DPD particles in a standard DPD simulation. Both usually have the form [Groot and Warren 1997]
$$
w^R(r) = F^C(r)/a = (1 - r)\quad \text{for } r<1 \text{, else }0
$$
I know that one can in principle choose a different weight function as long as it fulfils the fluctuation dissipation relation $(w^R)^2 = w^D$ but to my knowledge the above weight function is almost always chosen.

What is the reason that the weight function is chosen to be of the same form as the conservative force in most DPD simulations? What could be a reason to choose another weight function?

Sources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight functions should be continuous and vary from a maximum value at $r=0$ to zero at the cut-off. The linear function is the *simplest* and *computationally least expensive* function that satisfies this requirement. That's why it's used.

Note, however, that non-linear functions are occasionally used, e.g.

> Yaghoubi, S., et al. "New modified weight function for the dissipative force in the DPD method to increase the Schmidt number." EPL (Europhysics Letters) 110.2 (2015): 24002. [(link)](http://epljournal.edpsciences.org/articles/epl/abs/2015/08/epl17051/epl17051.html)

By the way, it may be useful for future reference to know that one of the inventors of DPD is an active member on this site: [Johannes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1268/johannes).